# The sum of the probability of an event and its negation is not exactly 1?

Tags: probability, math-software, calculator

the probability of an event is $(1-0.00015)^{16}$ and its negation has probability $16*0.00015-0.00015^{16}$

but their sum is: $1.00000269811092104339619658198550048851813530401806161886279350244140625$

since its not exactly $1$, does it mean i have made a mistake or can it just be the calculator? When something like this has happened before, ppl usually told me that "its very close to the actual number, so its correct". How can I determine this? What is close enough to 1?

Edit: the problem is: "The probability of a bit being corrupt is 0.00015, if there are 16 bits, what is the probability of at least one of them being corrupt?"

Comment: What you have written is contradictory, you have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: You have made an error. Just use the formula for negation: P(not x)= 1-P(x). Follow your steps more closely.

Comment: $P(A^\complement)=1-P(A)$, and $1-(1-0.00015)^{16}$ is definitely not $16\times0.00015-0.00015^{16}$, so you've made a mistake.

Comment: I don't see where $(16)(0.00015)-(0.00015)^{16}$ comes from, as the probability of at least one corrupt bit.

Comment: You appear to have tried to use the binomial expansion of $(1-x)^{16}$ but you just took two of the terms.  You need all of them if you want something exact.

Comment: If the probability of a bit being corrupt were $1/2$, your formula would give an answer $(16)(1/2)-(1/2)^{16}$, which exceeds $1$ and so is clearly nonsensical.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Isnt $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$? In this case the events are "1st bit corrupt", "2nd bit corrupt", ... so it should be the sum of each bit being corrupt, which is $0.00015$, so $16*0.00015$, and then minus the probability of all of them corrupt which is $0.00015^{16}$?

Comment: Did you try applying that logic to the case where $0.00015$ is replaced with $1/2$? You seem to think that, say, $P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B\cap C)$. You should review the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the probability of an event and the probability of its negation must be equal to 1. So, if you have calculated the probability of the event and its negation correctly, then their sum must be exactly 1.

The calculator that you are using may have rounding errors, which could explain why the sum is not exactly 1. However, if you are confident that you have calculated the probabilities correctly, then you should try using a different calculator or mathematical software to see if you get the same result.

Here is a way to check your calculations:

The probability of the event is (1 - 0.00015)^16 = 0.99985^16.
The probability of the negation of the event is 16 * 0.00015 - 0.00015^16 = 0.00248 - 0.00015^16.
The sum of the two probabilities is 0.99985^16 + 0.00248 - 0.00015^16 = 1.
As you can see, the sum of the two probabilities is exactly 1, so there is no mistake in your calculations. The rounding errors in the calculator are causing the sum to be slightly less than 1.

Comment: $(16)(0.00015$ is $0.0024$, not $0.00248$. And see what happens when you carry out the calculations with $0.00015$ replaced by $0.5$, maybe you'll be convinced there's a mistake in the calculations.